# MySQL process taking 150-400% CPU

Tags: php, mysql, server, process, centos

My software makes a lot of MySQL queries to my server, and I have never had any issues in the past with it, but just recently nothing was loading, no webpages, no SQL was running, nothing.  I managed to get on WHM for my server and kill the process, only to watch it spike back up to 300%.  Nothing I have been able to do has made it go down.  What information do I need to share to get help with this?  I am not a sys admin nor do I have one or resources for one.  I wouldn't usually be asking for help and just optimize all my queries for something like this as it wasn't a problem for the past 3 months but suddenly became one out of nowhere, at least not that I noticed.  At this point my program is saying that one of my database tables has crashed and needs repaired...  What can I do?  Thanks in advance for any help...

I have already considered optimization but I was hoping for a quick solution to implement as I have customers waiting, then I can spend a few days working on optimizing my SQL that, like I said, wasn't having any issues before.  I am confused about it.

Also I am not sure if this helps but tracing the process in WHM prints this repeatedly and nothing else:

```
fcntl(16, F_GETFL)                      = 0x2 (flags O_RDWR)
fcntl(16, F_SETFL, O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK)   = 0
accept(16, {sa_family=AF_LOCAL, NULL}, [2]) = 35
fcntl(16, F_SETFL, O_RDWR)              = 0
setsockopt(35, SOL_IP, IP_TOS, [8], 4)  = -1 EOPNOTSUPP (Operation not supported)
futex(0x13298a4, FUTEX_WAKE_OP_PRIVATE, 1, 1, 0x13298a0, {FUTEX_OP_SET, 0, FUTEX_OP_CMP_GT, 1}) = 1
futex(0x1327240, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
poll([{fd=14, events=POLLIN}, {fd=16, events=POLLIN}], 2, -1) = 1 ([{fd=16, revents=POLLIN}])
```

/etc/my.conf

```
innodb_file_per_table=1
default-storage-engine=MyISAM
performance-schema=0
max_allowed_packet=268435456
open_files_limit=10000
```

This is all that is available to me as far as `my.conf` file.  The error log doesn't exist in `/var/log` so I don't have anything to give in that regard...

SQL version:
`[Server] # mysql -V
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.41, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper`

I have an additional question or add-on to this. I don't know if it makes much of a difference but, say my code is running using 30% CPU on the mysql process, I can actually turn off the code and the mysql process CPU usage will not change.  What does this mean?

Edit: (these are all expiring within a week from 12/09/2018)

- [Global Status](https://pastebin.com/DTBSXckE)
- [Current Settings](https://pastebin.com/NGQYzcwQ)
- [ulimit -a](https://pastebin.com/yfxbxCTR)
- [df -h](https://pastebin.com/6APBPNJ1)
- [mysqltuner report](https://pastebin.com/THS6PzHn)

The my.cnf file contents that I listed is all that was there.  Nothing else.  I will get the `top` command and `iostat -xm 5 3` when I am running the software full speed again to see the results.

Comment: Best bet would be to restore a backup of your database on a separate server and use it until you can pin point the issue on the server. The extra CPU usage is more than likely due to MySQL attempting to recover the data from binary log or failed read/write attempts. But without knowing more it sounds like a hardware related issue such as bad hard drive sector, failing SSD or ram that caused corruption of the table data. You would need to share info from your mysql error log, your `my.cnf` settings (removing sensitive info like username/password).

Comment: Check MySQL logs, maybe as your program is saying you, have a crashed table

Comment: Ok.  My server hosting is through godaddy, I don't have anything quick to change to.  Do you have any recommendations?  The whole database is about 14GB with several tables with several million records in them that I have generated.  I suppose I can give them a call and hope somebody who knows what they are doing answers the phone.  Let me get error log and my.cnf settings.  The last time I looked at it though it only had 4 or 5 settings in it.  The table I had was crashed but I repaired it through PhpMyAdmin

Comment: Enable slow query log, are tables MyISAM or Innodb? What MySQL version (`SELECT VERSION()`)?

Comment: OK I will enable slow query log, tables are MyISAM as shown in my.conf and the version is also listed now. `5.6.41`

Comment: Slow query log is enabled.  SHould I paste the output here?

Comment: Since GoDaddy is hosting; their Tier 2 tech support should be able to provide you with support as to diagnosing and possibly resolving the issue, especially if it is hardware related, unless it is application caused. The slow query log will only pinpoint abnormal queries that take extensive time to run, but will not necessarily correlate with the CPU usage. Check the `/var/lib/mysql` directory or `SELECT @@log_error` for the log files there. You should see a `mysql-error.log` file which will show the service startup info and any errors, depending on your `log_error_verbosity` level.

Comment: Ya for sure.  I will try and give them a call in a few minutes.  I have let the slow query log run all night with my code and it didn't add anything to the log there.  I just checked out the error log which was under a different name for some reason.  Nothing seems out of the usual.  There is a little bit for an unresolved IP address, some for repairing the table and otherwise restarting the MySQL service as well as my server. (The only way I have found to clear the CPU).  Nothing obvious.

Comment: I don't know if it makes much of a difference but, say my code is running using 30% CPU on the mysql process, I can actually turn off the code and the mysql process CPU usage will not change.  What does this mean?  Additionally, even if I am very careful with it, the CPU usage will slowly creep upwards for some reason.  Say it's at 30%, and i let everything run, it will be at 90%, then 150% by this point the table is crashed but.  Beforehand when I made this post I started my software and the CPU was spiking to 350% but I have been careful since.  Could it be from unclosed connections?

Comment: It only means that the issue is not exhibited unless mysql is interacted in the manner the application is performing.  Like reads and/or writes to the database and/or specific tables or by calling certain procedures / triggers.  For example a MySQL function call being executed as an infinite loop. If there is nothing standing out in the error log and your verbosity is 3, then I would look at application level issues, such as infinite loops. PHP and MySQL have default connection timeouts, which you did not indicate you altered and PHP closes the connections after terminating each request.

Comment: For sure.  For the past few hours my CPU usage percentage has been fluctuating quite a bit for unapparent reasons.  My application is written in `Python` and uses `mysql.connector` library.  There doesn't seem to be any infinite loops as they would present themselves in the application I would imagine.  It definitely loops like an engine might but only until it stops.  I have been working the past few hours to eliminate unnecessary (extra) connections, as well as listing my queries to create indexes in the DB.  Not sure what else to do until I find another solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rate Per Second=RPS  Suggestions to consider based on your Linux ulimit -a report.

```
ulimit -n 16384       to raise Open Files limit from 1024 to support your activities.
```

For this to persist over Linux Shutdown/Restart, review this url.

https://glassonionblog.wordpress.com/2013/01/27/increase-ulimit-and-file-descriptors-limit/

Your specifics may be slightly different due to version of Linux.

Suggestions to consider for your my.cnf [mysqld] section

```
innodb_lru_scan_depth=100  # from 1024 to reduce CPU busy every second.  93% savings for this one function.
thread_cache_size=32  # from 9 for thread breathing room and growth.
innodb_io_capacity=1800  # from 200 to take advantage of your HDD IOPS capacity
key_cache_age_threshold=7200  # from 300 seconds to reduce key_reads RPS of 16 
query_cache_size=0  # from 1M to conserve RAM - QC is OFF and not used
query_cache_limit=0  # from 1M to conserve RAM - QC is OFF and not used
key_buffer_size=128M  # from 8M which had NO free space at the end of your work day
```

For additional suggestions, see my profile, Network profile for contact information.

Comment: @Pixelknight1398 Have you had time to apply the 7 suggestions posted Dec 11, 2018?  What is your current situation?  Happy Holidays.